# How to access Django Model Instance's "absolute_url" in a Python function through a Queryset

Tags: django

How to access the value / string , from defined method - get_absolute_url , through a Django ORM Queryset , within a python function within the views.py .

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the url to access a particular instance of the model."""
    return reverse('model-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Code above is a sample from the Mozilla developer Network . How to access - `model-detail-view` , for each instance of the model within below mentioned Queryset.

The code i have below doesn't give any results , rather the ERROR ==

```
queryset = myModel.objects.get_absolute_url()
```

AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Second try with the return value of the `reverse` method also fails with similar AttributeError.

```
queryset = myModel.objects.model-detail-view()
```

AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'model-detail-view'

Wanted to get individual - "model-detail-view" , strings and pass them to dataTable.js as part of a python DF , further passed on as JSON .

Comment: Please describe your desired result. If this is supposed to be a JSON - add sample JSON to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myModel.objects` is a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/), not an instance of that model class. You need to get an instance first, with something like:

```
instance = myModel.objects.get(pk=1)
instance.get_absolute_url()
```

If you want this result for an entire queryset, you can use:

```
urls = [obj.get_absolute_url() for obj in myModel.objects.all()]
```

This is just a starting point. You'll probably need to paginate the above, as it will otherwise be a very expensive query. Maybe look into [Django Rest Framework serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) if you want this in a more robust fashion.

Comment: Thanks - nimasmi , am sure this shall work , give me a few hours to test it and upvote+accept your answer - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @nimasmi , i can now access my model instance absolute url as seen here , the primary key is hardcoded to test your code ==

````
myModel_instance = csv_document.objects.get(pk=164)
 print(myModel_instance.get_absolute_url())      
#prints 
/dc/eda_action/CSV_Upload_to_psqlaacc47/```
````